# Is a dictionary of dictionaries the best solution here?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a collection of calendar event objects which have a date value which spans over a number of academic years ie 201213 201112 etc
I need to have the objects grouped first of all by year as the first enumeration over the collection is based on the academic year. Then I need to have the dates grouped by month. (The months also need to run backwards from the current date. Then every date in the month grouping needs to ordered descending from latests to earliest.

So I'm having a discussion with myself about the best way of doing this, I'm drawn to the idea of having  for each year having a key of the academic year which points to the value of a collection of dictionaries which again have a key of the month and then a collection of calendar event objects.

ie. `dictionary<string, dictionary<string, List<CalendarEvent>>`

My one concern about this method, is the sorting and ensuring the correct order is maintained as the objects are going to be used to create a timeline, where the first object on the timeline is latest. (Take the facebook timeline as an example of this, where facebook events are grouped by year and month and week and so on).

Is the above collection the best, or is there a simpler solution or path I can go down that I may not have considered ?

This collection is going to be passed to an MVC view, so the less massaging of the collection in the view the better, which is why I haven't gone down the path of List , the dates are also grouped by academic year which spans september - June , hence the string '201213'  for the academic year. So my intention is to loop once through the collection.

I intend to loop once through the dictionary and for each item in the dictionary loop again through the inner dictionary of months then loop again through the the actual calendar objects providing me with a chronological descending order of events for the time line.

With the events descending

ie ...

2013

July

--event 1 10th July

-- event 2 1st July

June

-- event x 30th June

-- event foo 1st June

2012

April

-- event bar 1st April

Comment: Please define "better" so question can be answered. Note that your current approach is clearly on "bad" side as you seem to be using `string` for numerical data (year is normally `int`, not a `string`).

Comment: It totally depends on how you are going to be using these objects. You could put them in a straight List and group/sort on the fly with LINQ whenever you need to. Without knowing what your usage pattern is this question is not very meaningful.

Comment: I share the same thought as Jon, List<DateTime> or similar may be sufficient with LINQ's orderby etc

Comment: I would rather create a simple custom object for this (Not a dictionary within a dictionary) Else your implementation code will look quite horrible to manage both dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you're over complicating the problem. If you're just talking a few years' worth of data, you could just use a two-dimensional array of `List<CalendarEvent>`:

```
const int NumYears = 100;
const int BaseYear = 2012;
List<CalendarEvent>[,] MyEvents = new List<CalendarEvent>[NumYears, 12];
```

So to get the list for for January 2014, you would write:

```
List<CalendarEvent> jan2014 = MyEvents[2014 - BaseYear, 0];
```

This doesn't take up a whole lot of space, and it's dead simple to work with. The array itself only takes `100*12*(sizeof IntPtr)` bytes. So about 4,800 bytes on a 32-bit machine or 9,600 bytes on a 64-bit machine. Each list that you allocate will of course require more space, but if there are no events for a particular month then you don't have to pay that cost. And if most months have events, this is going to take a lot less space than a dictionary.

If your academic year is Sept through June and you're worried about space, you can make the second rank have only 10 elements and have methods that convert your month/year (say, January 2014) to the proper index (which I assume would be the 4th month of the 2013 academic year). I probably wouldn't worry about it, though. We're only talking 200 null references for 100 years worth of data. It'd probably take more than that amount of code to express the special conditions.

As far as the individual events are concerned, there probably aren't very many in a particular month so it doesn't really make sense trying to keep them in chronological order. Just do an `OrderBy` on the list to sort by date when it's time to enumerate them. Sorting that small number of events won't take any appreciable time.

It should be pretty easy to wrap that all up in a class that implements `IEnumerable<CalendarEvent>` and guarantees proper enumeration order.

Another option would be to use a simple `List<CalendarEvent>` as the backing store and just throw the events into it in any order. Then if you want to display all the events for a particular academic year or range of years (or even a single month or date) you can use a LINQ select and order by (descending?) to pick out the ones you want. It really depends on how many events, total, you're working with and how often you'll have to massage it. If the total number of events is in the thousands or maybe even in the tens of thousands, the selection and sorting is going to take milliseconds. This is probably the way I'd go if the numbers are as small as I suspect they are.

Comment: Thanks Jim i'll give it a whirl, I was hoping the solution I was coming up with was convoluted.

Comment: This is the kind of comment that makes me love StackOverflow.   It is really valuable to get different brains to consider a strategy, and reality-check it for you.  This was a nice piece of analysis, and has the potential to save the OPer a lot of work and pain.  Well done.

Comment: @MikeRayner: See my update. A simple `List<CalendarEvent>` might be the way to go.

Comment: I went with your 2nd solution, much simpler, and involved less nesting within my view as I looped through the entries.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not guaranteed to enumerate in any particular order.    A tree of SortedList or SortedDictionary collections would probably do what you're trying to do.

Perhaps you should use a collection (like List) that supports IComparable.

Comment: You can use `OrderBy` on a dictionary after which enumerating it will happen in the order you specified.

Comment: Only through Linq? As long as the Dictionary is sorted first, you can enumerate it using `foreach` in that specific order just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree), with points keyed by time, is probably a better idea. Here's [some helpful slides](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/RangeSearching.pdf) about them.

A range tree would require a lot less housekeeping, since the only thing the tree cares about is the exact time. It is independent of the human constructs like months and years, which is great because human constructs are terrible terrible things (e.g. months actually end at many different times due to time zones). The human stuff would only come into the picture when deciding what range to query.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this solution, which is easy to implement and maintain ; use a :

```
SortedDictionary<YearMonth, Event>
```

The YearMonth class should implement IComparable, where you can specify that years and month have a descending order.

Cheers

Comment: This looks more favorable, I hadn't considered a key which can use both year and month to get what I need. I'll try it out and see if it provides the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

Since every event will have a date you create each with an appropriate one and event description,i made an calendarevent class and month enum for easy display:

```
    public enum NameOfMonth
    {
        january = 1,
        febuary,
        march,
        april,
        may,
        june,
        july,
        august,
        september,
        october,
        november,
        december
    }

    class CalendarEvent
    {
        public NameOfMonth month;
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string eventdescription { get; set; }

        public CalendarEvent()
        {

        }
    }
```

Then you create a list with each calendarevent object(each one of course with a description,date,so on...),and then group it by year creating an anonymous object and ordering by month and then by day,after its just display them:

```
            List<CalendarEvent> myevents = new List<CalendarEvent>()
            {
                new CalendarEvent(){date = new DateTime(2005,1,17),eventdescription = "Armaggedon",month = NameOfMonth.january},
                new CalendarEvent(){date =  new DateTime(2005,3,20),eventdescription = "Apocalypse",month = NameOfMonth.march},
                new CalendarEvent(){date = new DateTime(2007,5,20),eventdescription = "WorldPeace",month = NameOfMonth.may},
                new CalendarEvent(){date = new DateTime(2009,2,20),eventdescription = "LaundryDay",month = NameOfMonth.febuary},
                new CalendarEvent(){date = new DateTime(2009,4,15),eventdescription = "MentalHealth",month = NameOfMonth.april},
                new CalendarEvent(){date = new DateTime(2009,6,10),eventdescription = "ProgrammingInC#",month = NameOfMonth.june},
                new CalendarEvent(){date = new DateTime(2009,6,12),eventdescription = "EraseAllYourWork?",month = NameOfMonth.june},
                new CalendarEvent(){date = new DateTime(2010,10,20),eventdescription = "SomeVeryNiceEvent",month = NameOfMonth.october},
                new CalendarEvent(){date = new DateTime(2010,8,21),eventdescription = "WellAnotherEvent",month = NameOfMonth.august}
            };
            var result = myevents2.GroupBy(d => d.date.Year)
                      .Select(g => new { Year = g.Key, data = g.OrderByDescending(k => k.date.Month).ThenByDescending(day => day.date.Day) })
                      .ToList();

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Events on ***" + item.Year + "***");
                foreach (var subitems in item.data)
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(subitems.month.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("On day " + subitems.date.Day + " - " + subitems.eventdescription);
                }
            }
```